# Best way to save UIImages for displaying them in my App?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I am working on an App which is taking photos of the user every day. Everything works fine and the Images get saved to the device. I currently can access them from the standard photos applicaltion.

In the next step of programming the application, I like to build a gallery in my App. I am thinking of iCarousel, but I am not sure yet.

Now I like to know **which is the best way to save the images** the user makes of himself? The user should be able to access the pictures by using the standard photos application on the device **and** in my gallery in my App. I am targeting iOS 8.1.

Currently I am saving the photos like this:

```
- (void)takePhoto{
    NSLog(@"CameraController: takePhoto()");

    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

    for(AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections){
        for(AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]){
            if([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]){
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(videoConnection){
            break;
        }
    }
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if(imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) { //this code gets executed if a photo is taken
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *combined = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            //....            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combined, nil, nil, nil);
                    NSLog(@"CameraController: Image saved");
                });
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Which version of iOS are you targetting?

Comment: Oh, sorry. iOS 8.1. I'll edit this in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using iCarousel now. I use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);` for generating a path for the pictures I like to save and to display in iCarousel.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about (and use) [PhotoKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html).